# Exchange Server 2013 and SharePoint Server 2013 on same Box

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server

I understand that we do not want to install SP2013 and Exhcnage 2013 on the same box in production environments, but my question is about a development VM.

Is it possible to install these two servers successfully on the same box. I have tried, but so far the Exchange install does not appear to complete successfully and I don't know if it is because of something I'm missing or if there is something that prohibits them running together.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Exchange Setup failed so first things first is to use Exchange Server Setup to completely remove the non-functioning Exchange.
It's preferred to remove SharePoint also.

After that, install Exchange Server first, then SharePoint. Then do some additional work (see links below) to configure them. If Exchange Setup continues to fail, seek for other solutions.

However, **I strongly suggest you install separate VMs to host Exchange and SharePoint on separate OS installations.**

Reference:

[Installing Sharepoint on the same server as Exchange and Remote Web Access (IIS – Sharepoint -RWA – OWA Conflicts)](https://davejsteele.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-sharepoint-on-the-same-server-as-exchange-and-remote-desktop-web-access-iis-sharepoint-rdweb-owa-conflicts/)

[Can be Install Exchange Server 2010 and SharePoint 2010 on the same server without any conflict?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/75a00f2f-89bd-4922-9af2-575dc2f0bd1a/can-be-install-exchange-server-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-on-the-same-server-without-any-conflict?forum=exchange2010)

It won't differ very much between Exchange and SharePoint 2010 and 2013 so the links above should also apply.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the links you've provided. Unfortunately, separate VMs is not an option, but if I can get both installs on the same VM, it will work for my purposes. I have previously created a SharePoint 2010 with Exchange 2010 VM that works (for my purposes) flawlessly.

Comment: I have overcome the issue with Exchange not installing completely and have found that it does work with SharePoint installed (again, I understand that this is not what we want to do in practice, but for my purposes, it is necessary).  The only thing I am struggling with is an error that I get when attempting to access Exchange's /ecd web utility. I get an "Online Web Application Error" indicating that i might already be signed in and that i should sign out and clear cookies. Also (and this is more minor) I am getting certificate warnings relating to the certificate generated during the install